# How do I do this? I can't find logic here

Tags: python, python-3.x

You have K toys numbered 1 to K and N boxes numbered 1 to N. You put the toys in the boxes in the following order:

first toy in the first box, second toy in the second box,

so up to N-th toy in the Nth box, the next toy in (N-1)-th box, the next toy in (N-2)-th box

and so on up to the first box, then the next toy in the second box ...... and so on until there is no toy left.

So you put the toy in the boxes in the following order: 1,2,3,....,N,N-1,N-2,....,2,1,2,3,....,N,N-1,....

Find the index of the box where you put the K-th toy

Yeah i need Python code for above mentioned problem

Comment: please show us what you tried (code)

Comment: Is K always bigger than N?

Comment: Try to solve for small `K` and `N`: say `K=10`, `N=3` first

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Forget Python for a minute.  Do you know how to solve this problem with pencil and paper?

Comment: Instead of providing you some python code I would suggest a general and simple solution:
Create boxes from 1, 2 ... N, N+1, N + 2, ... , N+N-1 and find the proper index for each toy by calculating (K % (2*N - 1)) as index . After each K is assigned to one of the boxes, you can merge the boxes properly by putting the content of Box 1 together with the content of box 2*N -1 ... then  putting the content of Box 2 together with the content of box 2*N -2 and so forth (in general merge Box with index x and 2*N - x  for each x from 1 ... N). btw. the box with index N needs not to be merged at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Except the first turn needs N toys (say 1st to N-th toy into 1st to Nth box), all turn will just need N-1 toys (ex: 2nd turn take N-1 toys for from (N-1)th box to 1st box).

So basic we let (K-1) (to define that first turn needs N toys) devided (N-1). Then if the result is even then the toys is putted from 1 to N, and odd means N to 1; the excess of division will gives you the position of K-th toys.

The code will go like this:

```
def put_K_to_N(k:int, n:int):
    res = (k-1)//(n-1)
    excess = (k-1)%(n-1)
    if res % 2:
        return n - excess
    else:
        return 1 + excess
```

Say if `k=10`, `n=3`:

```
output = put_K_to_N(10, 3)
```

Then you will get `output = 2`